# How to update the uid of a node in node revision table?

Tags: 7, rules

Is there any way to update the node's `uid` in the `node revision` table using [rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

I have used the `node:author` but it only update the `uid` in the `node` table and does not update in the `node revision` table.

Is there any other way?

Comment: the uid in the node_revision table will be updated with the author when the user creates the new revision. What are you expecting to trigger the change?

Answer (score 0):

Along with what Japo said, the latest revision will mirror the update, it does not get applied retroactively, not sure why you would want that specifically. Unless this is a case where anonymous users create content or are assigned content and you want them to have edit access to all past revisions?

Either way, nothing will solve this for you short of a custom module that does a db query to force the UID value on the table.

Comment: The problem is when I update the node author in the rules, it makes the uid 0 in the node revision. Why it is changing to 0? any reason?

Comment: No idea, unless that is the value or it cannot determine the value. I don't use Rules very often.